# Xamarin Forms: scrollview with button fixed on bottom xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to xamarin forms and xaml and i want try to reproduce this layout in xaml
[image: YPlan app]

A scrollable view with an image, then a description and, fixed on bottom, a button (that not scroll with the view)

How can i achieve this layout in xamarin forms? I must use StackLayout or Grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This should do it. A stack layout, which contains a scrollview for your scrollable content, then your two buttons under it inside of a horizontal stacklayout.

```
<stacklayout>

     <scrollview>
     </scrollview>

     <stacklayout orientation=horizontal>
            <share button>   <get tickets button>
     </stacklayout>

</stacklayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a StackLayout it's a good choice. You should have a StackLayout that contains a ScrollView (that contains a StackLayout for Image and Labels) and the StackLayout (Orientation = Horizontal) for "Share" and "Get tickets" buttons (or a Grid for these buttons....)